# Can a DC voltage source be used for a transformer?

Tags: transformer, dc

Can we use a pulsating DC source, such as the waveform \$v(t)=10+\sin(\omega t)\$, to drive a transformer?

Since the voltage changes sinusoidally, shouldn't the flux also change and produce an induced voltage in the secondary?

Comment: Do you think the the DC offset (the 10) might cause the transformer core to saturate?

Comment: Webers is measured in volt-seconds -- the integral of applied volts times the infinitesimal of time. The "10" there is a constant. Over time, this will integrate towards infinity. Not good for a transformer with a core other than vacuum. Once the core saturates out, it will act like a vacuum.

Comment: I've seen a big industrial manufacturer chop straight 24VDC at 150kHz into a ferrite gate-pulse transformer as a means of providing isolated low-power supplies.  Just have to be careful not to saturate the core in that time (Volt-microseconds.)

Comment: Your title says DC **current** source but, for whatever reason, your formula is implying a voltage source. So the answer to your title question depends on what source is used.

Comment: If the voltage changes sinusoidally, it's no longer a DC source--it has some AC component as well as a DC component.

Comment: @periblepsis isn't current what causes saturation? and it is limited by resistance

Comment: @user253751 Why do you think so?

Comment: @periblepsis a transformer core designed for say 5A with a constant DC 1A flowing will not be saturated

Comment: @user253751 So? This has nothing to do with the questioner's applied voltage with offset question, nor does it address how it is that core saturation of solid state materials occur. I don't need to respond because there's nothing there to respond to. Nice try.

Comment: A "pulsating DC source" is not a DC source. It's an AC source with really messy spectrum.

Comment: While whether a transformer can handle DC offset is an interesting question, practically speaking it may be simpler to first remove that offset with a coupling capacitor.

Answer (score 8):

If the voltage across the primary varies, you will see something happen on the secondary, yes. It's not about the voltage across the primary going from positive to negative and back, but about the voltage *changing*. The resulting varying current will generate a varying magnetic field which will induce a voltage in the secondary.

The DC component, however, drives a DC current through the primary which can saturate the core, lowering the inductance, which you usually don't want.

A core that is *constantly* fully saturated because of a DC component can't change flux anymore and won't induce a current in the secondary. An intermittently saturated core will distort the wave shape.

Comment: *which will induce a current in the secondary* <-- It induces a voltage in the secondary not a current.

Comment: The DC current also wastes huge amounts of power and could melt the transformer's insulation; surprised nobody's mentioning this.

Answer (score 6):

From the question's title (now fixed by the OP): -

> *Can a DC current source be used for a transformer?*

Yes it can providing the source current doesn't excessively saturate the transformer core. The more the core saturates the less useful the transformer becomes.

From the question's body: -

> *Can we use a pulsating DC source, such as the waveform
> \$v(t)=10+sin(ωt)\$, to drive a transformer?*

No we can't because the DC current will continue to ramp upwards to a value that saturates the core or the DC source voltage becomes current limited.

Also, if \$\omega\$ is too low you will also get a similar problem.

Answer (score 5):

What will happen when you connect DC with an AC component, as your equation describes, to a transformer? The AC component will couple to the secondary, but the DC will not. The secondary will only have current induced by a varying field, not the static DC one. Stated another way, transformers block DC current and pass AC.

Will there be other issues, like the transformer core saturating? Depends on the currents involved and the transformer characteristics. Despite that concern, merging DC and AC onto the same line has practical applications.

Example: PoE (Power-over-Ethernet) uses AC signals superimposed onto DC power. The signals and power are merged at one end and separated at the other using, you guessed it, transformers. Ethernet signal rates are relatively high so the transformers are small, often hidden away as part of the RJ45 jack.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly how the traditional thermionic-valve based A-class audio amplifiers and some radio frequency amplifiers are built.

The primary of a transformer is driven by the pulsating anode current of the tube. At the secondary, you get the amplified (AC) signal.

In this case, one doesn't get much of a DC voltage over the primary because the primary has little DC resistance, but the DC current is generally more than the AC current.

These transformers are designed to withstand the DC current without saturating or overheating.

A random example from the 'net:
[image]
[Image credit](https://www.heatedcathode.com/3w-single-ended-class-a-stereo-tube-amplifier/)

See how the T1 transformer and the EL84 tube are connected.

Answer (score 0):

If a rated DC voltage is applied to the primary of the transformer, the flux produced in the transformer core will not vary but it remains constant in magnitude and therefore no emf will be induced in secondary winding, also there will be no self induced emf in the primary winding is quite low, therefore a heavy current will draw through the primary winding. So the DC supply is never applied to a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have already made clear that the DC component can cause a problem by saturating the transformer.

What can be a little less obvious (but remains true) is that it takes a short amount of time for a magnetic flux to "collapse" in the transformer core. When your input is AC, as the voltage reverses, it's actively reversing the previous flux, so (as as long as the frequency is within the range for which the transformer was designed) you basically just get a slight phase difference between the voltage and the flux (black is voltage, red is flux):

[image]

But even if our pulsed DC actually drops all the way to zero, such as if we started with AC, and ran it through a full-wave rectifier:

[image]

We no longer have voltage that's actively reversing the magnetic field. Instead, just as the flux is collapsing, the voltage starts to rise again, and starts increasing the flux again. It never fully collapses, so looking at both voltage and flux, we get something like this:

[image]

Our flux never actually drops to zero, and the secondary only responds to the change in flux, so it's still somewhat less efficient than it was with AC input (even though the voltage has no constant DC component "under" the ripple).

Comment: Hi, is this phase difference due to hysteresis?

Comment: @insipidintegrator: Yes. Or I suppose if you want to be grammatically correct, it's not really caused *by* hysteresis; that time lag *is* hysteresis.

Answer (score -2):

How do you think a coil works in a car? producing that high voltage spark..

Also called autotransformers and they have a capacitor so the points which are the switch do not arc too much.